# Missing CMS Pages

Tags: database, cms

We are servicing a site that has "Clever CMS" installed. It essentially creates a catalog-like tree for cms pages. A customer accidentally deleted the page in the admin but the URL still works on the front end. I've recreated the page in the admin but cannot use the same url.

In the database if I deleted the old record in the "cms_page_tree" table will that make the URL available for the new page? Im just worried about any identifer being anywhere else that would hold that URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if you're still seeing the page in the front-end then it's either a different page being shown (through some sort of redirect) or it' sbeing cached somehow. You should try clearing cache since it's pretty hard to fix something if you're not totally sure what's real or not.

That being said, you should not see the record in the cms_page_tree table if you deleted the record. You may actually be looking at the wrong database, or the wrong page somehow. In my use of cms_page_tree I didn't see any kind of model persist behavior, so it's quite strange. You could always copy the row's SQL insert statement (most editors can do this), delete it, check the frontend, then re-insert the row if things don't pan out.